# Pycma - fmin Iterations

Tags: python, fminsearch

I'm using the library pycma to try and minimize some function by using the wrapper function `cma.fmin`.

But for the life of me I can't figure out how many iterations this function runs for, and I'm a bit short on time. Any ideas on what parameter controls the number of iterations? And what is the default amount of iterations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`maxfevals`](http://cma.gforge.inria.fr/apidocs-pycma/cma.purecma.html#fmin) is the parameter that you want I think because it is for:

> maximal number of function evaluations, a string is evaluated with N as search space dimension